# Merging multiple images creates broken image

Tags: php, image

So I'm attempting to create an array of names, take the image that is associated with that name, and merge them all together.  The code below seems to just return a broken image.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$startLink = file_get_contents("http://websiteforimage.com/1/img.png");
$start = imagecreatefromstring($startLink);
$name = array("2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
foreach($name as $value){
    $link = "http://websiteforimage.com/" . $value . "/img.png";
    $img = imagecreatefrompng($link);
    $offset = imagesx($start) + imagesx($img);
    imagecopymerge($start, $img, $offset, 0, 64, 64, 64, 64, 100);
}
imagepng($start);

?>
```

Any clue on how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial thoughts would be the imagecopymerge() function.
You don't clearly state how you're merging them but I'm going to assume it's from left to right?

In that case, your co-ordinates seem wrong

```
$start  - sure, that's the first image
$img    - yes, that's the new image to attach
$offset - makes sense, that's where the new image is going to start on destination
0       - makes sense too, as we are starting at the very top
64      - makes no sense to me as you are saying the you want to start 64 pixels in on the new image
64      - makes no sense again as you want to start 64 pixels down on your source image
64      - I assume the source is 64 pixels wide
64      - ...and 64 pixels high?
```

So assuming you really did mean to do that, then it all appears fine.
My only other question would be regarding the function itself. I always thought imagecopymerge would only work if the the place you wanted to put your source existed on the destination. Eg, if the destation is 100 pixels wide and 100pixels high and you wanted to put an image it at 99pixels from the left and 99pixels from the top, then there's only 1 pixel to play with and it doesn't magically increase the dimensions of the destination.

So taking that into account I'm pretty sure your first image needs to be large enough in advance to take on board the other images otherwise they simply won't appear if their X,Y co-ordinates are larger than the dimensions of the destination. Don't quote me on that though, it's just food for thought!

Good luck.

Oh, follow up - You might want to check this out as a guide? it appears to be doing the same thing http://diceattack.wordpress.com/2011/01/03/combining-multiple-images-using-php-and-gd/

Comment: Thanks!  I guess I just assumed the imagecopymerge would adjust the images size if I placed the new image past the original image's dimensions.  Though, that website does seem to be doing exactly what I want - Thanks!